# Return range as a global variable Google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, global-variables

I am trying to create a global variable of parsed json data.

I want to use the global variable in other functions

The json parsing works great but I am having no luck with the global variable creation

```
async function GETELEMENTS(url) {
  var response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var responseText = await response.getContentText();
  var responseJson = JSON.parse(responseText);
  var elementKeys = Object.keys(responseJson.elements[0]);
  
  var data = responseJson.elements.map(e => elementKeys.map(f => {
      return e[f] instanceof Array ? e[f].join('|') : e[f];
  }));
  data.unshift(elementKeys);
  
  if(data.length==0)
   return;
 
  }
  
  var cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  cache.put('A', data);
  var cache = CacheService.getPublicCache();

  return data;
}
```

where `cache.get('A')` is esseintaly  `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();` of the returned data

Then in a different function, I want to use

```
myotherfunction(cache.get('A'));
```

Comment: [mcve].........

Comment: What doesn't work with your current  approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare `data` **outside** of every function and it will automatically be a **global** variable.

### Minimal reproducible example:

```
var data;

function GETELEMENTS() {
  data = 'I was defined!';
}


function myotherfunction(){

  Logger.log(data); // -> output: null
  GETELEMENTS();
  Logger.log(data); // -> output: I was defined!

}
```

If you **execute** `myotherfunction`, **after** the line `GETELEMENTS()` the `data` will have the value `I was defined!` defined in `GETELEMENTS()`.